# How to update the authorization server user details using access/id tokens?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

Created new endpoint /user to update the user details. Header has access token, still the authorization is failed to invoke the user end point.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1136

Comment: Please provide some details, and code. Otherwise it's impossible to figure out where the problem is

Comment: @AndreyGrigoriev Here is the repository https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/

Comment: @Thirumal, great to see you're exploring a full featured authorization server implementation! However, this question still does not have any details. Your repository is not minimal enough to distill the problem. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or alternatively describe the steps to use the [default authorization server sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver) and the exact request you're trying to make.